# How do w3m's "buttons" wok?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, tui

I've been playing with C#'s `Spectre.Console`, and I'm now planning a T/CUI app, however I  was wondering how the w3m web browser gets it's console based buttons?

For example, I want something like this:

```
[I am a button]
```

But when you hover over it with your cursor, and press enter the "button" gets pressed.

How would this work, programatically? I know you could just check where the cursor is and if they hit enter at x,y - x,y then they "pressed" the button, however this feels like a hack, and I think there's a better way somehow.

Thanks, Gammer0909